# Windows 7 taskbar buttons have wrong geometry (height)

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

In Windows 7, the taskbar buttons are too low (or the taskbar is too high - I don't know what is true). The taskbar with Classic design and classic taskbar settings looks like:

[image: Taskbar with too low buttons]

As you can see this looks "unnatural" or "buggy" because there are many grey pixels under the taskbar buttons.

On the other hand, if I resized the taskbar to hold two rows, everything looks fine:

[image: Correct taskbar with 2 rows]

It seems that the problem is related to the userprofile (which was recovered from a previous installation).

I tried resizing or changing settings back and forth: no change.

Therefore the answer to the question could be the answer to:

"Where does Windows (7) save settings of the taskbar geometry?"

In this case, I could delete this data so that default settings are restored.

Comment: Did you first try in display personalisation to load up the default "Windows classic" and to switch to say one of the high contrasts, then switch back?  I was thinking Icon size, or title bar size in "window color" where a lot of these metrics are adjusted, but it was not those 2, how about border padding.  Are you running ANY other shell substitute , start menu changer, classic shell, or any of the add-on start or taskbar, 2 monitor taskbar programs? (because it would be blowing in the breeze to not know that).

Comment: On top of the Start menu, right click & select "Properties", in the Taskbar tab, switch "Use Small Icons", then ok out, then switch it back again. as another possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Sometimes pinned programs can mess with the classic theme since their minimum height may be greater than the taskbar height.
2. What's in your system tray? Some modules can interfere; e.g. on my ThinkPad, the ThinkPad Power Manager battery icon displays next to the system tray, and is higher than a classic single taskbar row, and so it does this.

In any case, it has nothing to do with Windows storing incorrect geometry or anything like that: Something in your taskbar is higher than the height of a single row - and Windows is adjusting to accommodate it; you need to find out what it is. Be sure to set your taskbar to use small icons, and hide any programs that may be adding large elements to the system tray. Also try unpinning whatever that application is.